# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "id goes here" at path "_id" for model "Article"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm experiencing something a little strange and was wondering if someone can help me out. I have a MEAN application that is able to retrieve ALL records from MongoDB perfectly but when I try to retrieve just 1 record by id, I'm getting a CastError. I even tried to downgrade my version of Mongo but the problem still persist. Any help would be great. Thanks

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Article = require('../models/article');


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Article.getArticles(function (err, articles) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.json(articles);

      }
  });
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Article.getArticleById(req.params.id, function (err, article) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.json(article);
      }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true);

var articleSchema =  mongoose.Schema({

    title: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        required: true
    }
});

var Article = module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);

// Get all articles
module.exports.getArticles = function (callback) {
    Article.find(callback);
};

// Get article by ID
module.exports.getArticleById = function (id, callback) {
     Article.findById(id, callback);

};
```

```html
[CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "58753da5d192f1aa25ebdd00" at path "_id" for model "Article"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "58753da5d192f1aa25ebdd00" at path "_id" for model "Article"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"58753da5d192f1aa25ebdd00"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '58753da5d192f1aa25ebdd00',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be a known bug in the latest version of Mongoose. I'd recommend downgrading to 4.7.2:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4867

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be on your view templating engine. make sure the route to the specific id is properly defined.

Comment: <ul class="list-group">
          <% posts.forEach((post)=>{%>
                 <a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>"><li class="list-group-item"><%= post.title 
                %></li></a>
      <% })%>
</ul>