# Angular/bluebird or other upgrades causing Mongoose “CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value…”

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, bluebird

I seem to have created some kind of upgrade conundrum.  I am using the mean stack built around version Angularjs version 1.4.x.  I decided to start the path of upgrading to 1.6 and then 2.x.   My first step was to move my code to another directory so I could have a working copy of the code for reference.   After migrating to the new directory the code was mostly working but I was getting a mongoose: mpromise error.  I was using native $q.  As I read about the suggested fixes I decided to bring in the bluebird module and add the line, mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird').  This made the mpromise issue go away but now my code to find a single record was no longer working (find of a collection does work).  My request to findone record, code below, started giving the CastError.

As I read through similar Stack Overflow questions I saw two suggested fixes.  One was to apply the mongoose.types.ObjectId function and the other made reference to upgrades.  I tried a number of combinations and my efforts to change the id to an Object id went unrewarded.  Depending on the way I structured either Object ID was not a function or the item was undefined.

I decided to try the upgrade route.  I have upgraded mongoose (4.7.6) and mongodb (3.4.1).  Below are the versions in my package.json and bower.json files.  Can anyone see this to be a version issue or am I doing something else wrong?

```
Package.json

"bluebird": "^3.4.7",
"body-parser": "^1.14.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
"express": "^4.13.3",
"express-session": "^1.12.1",
"jade": "^1.11.0",
"mongoose": "^4.7.6",
"morgan": "^1.6.1",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"stylus": "^0.52.4"

Bower.json
"jquery": "~2.1.4",
"toastr": "~2.1.2",
"angular": "~1.4.8",
"angular-resource": "~1.4.8",
"angular-route": "~1.4.8",
"bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
"angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
"angular-input-dropdown": "~1.0.1",
"angular-xeditable": "~0.1.12",
"bluebird": "~3.4.7",
"angular-bluebird-promises": "~1.0.2"


games.js
var Game = require('mongoose').model('Game');
//var mongoose = require('mongoose');
exports.getGameById = function(req,res) {
console.log("Get - games.getGameById");
//var gameId = '584349fcdc19b2582183e80e';
var gameId =  req.params.id;
//var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');
//var _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.fromString(id);
//ObjectId.fromString( myObjectIdString );

console.log("req.params " + req.params);
console.log("req.query " + req.query);
console.log("req.params.id " + req.params.id);
console.log("req.query.id " + req.query.id);
console.log("req.url " + req.url);
console.log("gameId " + gameId);
console.dir(req.params);
keys = Object.keys(req.params);
console.log(keys);
Game.findOne({_id: gameId }).exec(function(err,game){
    if (err){
        console.log("Error - No Game Retrieved");
        console.log("Get - games.getGames (Id) - Error");
        console.log("Error = " + err);
        res.send(null);
    }else
    {
        console.log("No Error - Game Data Retrieved");
        console.log("Get - games.getGames (Id) - No Error");
        console.log("Returned - game " + game)
        console.log("Get - games.getGames (Id) - Sending Back Game");
        res.send(game);
    }
})
};
```

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578800/casterror-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-id-goes-here-at-path-id-for-mo

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I installed 4.7.2 and now it is working.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I have another question.  After downgrading per the line,  npm install mongoose@4.7.2 , I checked the version and the response using, npm view mongoose version, was 4.7.6.   Any idea why the higher version would come back?